# apt-get update Rootless Docker

Tags: docker, updates, apt-get, rootless, unattended-upgrade

Installing Rootful Docker on my Raspberry Pi updates the sources and one can configure `unattended-upgrades` to update Docker automatically by looking at `sudo apt-cache policy`.

However, Rootless Docker doesn't. So is there a way to upgrade Rootless Docker ?

#### In other words:

With Rootful Docker, `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade` on the host could upgrade the Docker installation. I would like to be able to do something similar with Rootless Docker.
Is it possible ?

To clarify: I am not trying to update the containers, but Docker itself.

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide :)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there isn't special rootless package for Debian so you can't do that with package manager. Some rootless binaries are bit different, [missing SETUID bits](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#how-it-works) and some other file capabilities.

However, you can try to run [rootless installation script](https://docs.docker.com/engine/security/rootless/#install) again, if that updates your binaries.

```
curl -fsSL https://get.docker.com/rootless | sh
```

These are also available here as [rootless-extras](https://download.docker.com/linux/static/stable/) , but it requires manual extraction:

Answer (score 1):

I also found no official way to update a docker-rootless installation.
So here is how i update docker-rootless. its a bit experimental, but it works for me. maybe it needs some more tests to make it more robust and ready to be usable in a script or crontab:

```
# UPDATE DOCKER-ROOTLESS (as user which docker-rootless runs with):
# stop your docker daemon ... (takes long time for me and doesn't finish problerly)
systemctl --user stop docker.service

# maybe you have to kill it because it hangs up and doesn't finish proberly
CTRL+C

# check that docker.service isn't running (important !!!)
systemctl --user status docker.service
# Active: inactive (dead)
# OR:
# Active: failed (Result: exit-code)

# download docker-rootless installation script
wget https://get.docker.com/rootless -O rootless.sh

# set environment variables (used by rootless.sh script)
SKIP_IPTABLES=1
FORCE_ROOTLESS_INSTALL=1

# remove "Already installed verification" check from script
sed -i s#\-x\ \"\$BIN/\$DAEMON\"#\!\ \-x\ \"\$BIN/\$DAEMON\"#g rootless.sh

# make rootles.sh executable
chmod +x rootless.sh

# run rootless.sh
./rootless.sh

# kill installation script, because it starts docker.service and keeps running
CTRL+C

# finally setcap cap_net_bind_service (to bind ports less than 1024)
# replace 'docker' with the username you are logged in with
sudo setcap cap_net_bind_service=ep /home/docker/bin/rootlesskit

# DONE (docker should now be updated)
docker --version
# Docker version 20.10.6, build 370c289


# UPDATE DOCKER-COMPOSE (with sudo or root):
# get and save latest docker-compose version
DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION=$(curl -L "https://docs.docker.com/compose/install/" | grep -o -P '(?<=https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/).*(?=/docker-compose)' | head -n1)

# download docker-compose
sudo curl -L "https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/$DOCKER_COMPOSE_VERSION/docker-compose-$(uname -s)-$(uname -m)" -o /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# make it executable
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose

# link it to /usr/bin
sudo ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose

# DONE (docker-compose should now be updated)
docker-compose --version
# docker-compose version 1.29.1, build c34c88b2


# remove docker-rootless script
rm rootless.sh

# maybe you should reboot your host once!
sudo reboot
```